# How to change the attributes in "Quick simple product creation"?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

I need to change the dimensions and size of the product in compound products using **Quick simple product creation** in an associate product.

So how can I ***add more attributes*** there and along with that how to *quick edit* these attributes later from the list show at bottom

[image]

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

1. Attribute is required
2. Attribute is applied to simply products but not configurable products
3. Attribute is not already attached to the configurable product
4. Or attribute is part of the blocks "core" attributes that must always be set from this form,

So simply if your attributes are set-up correctly they should appear in this form.